# .htaccess Rewrite breaks relative file path?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, src

I decided to keep the CMS I develop for my website outside of the document root directory for security reasons. The CMS is accessed when you type example.com/cms/ in the address bar. So in the root directory, I created a PHP file, which is called from .htaccess and the file redirects to the address. Everything so far works, but when I try to access a resource from the CMS folder with relative path it isn't found.

The .htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/.*$ index.cms.php [NC,L]
```

index.cms.php:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../cms/index.php');
```

A path in the index.php file in the 'cms' directory:

```
src="res/username.png"
```

How the browser reads it:

```
example.com/cms/res/password.png
```

The directory is actually located one directory above the root and should be something like this:

```
/../cms/res/password.png
```

I also tried adding

```
<base href="/"/>
```

to the head but it doesn't really help.

Sorry for the silly question but I am really stuck on this.

Comment: The point of putting things *outside* the document root is that they **can't** be accessed over HTTP. So it's fine for things you want to include server-side (PHP class files for example, that aren't accessed directly) but not for things that need to be accessed by the client (e.g. images).

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should store the resources in the root directory.

Comment: Well, they need to be somewhere under the docroot yeah. If it's a directory that's just going to hold static resources (images, css, js) you could disable PHP on that directory by adding in `php_engine off` in an `.htaccess` file (or better yet a main Apache conf if you can) - it's normally not a bad idea if that's somewhere that's likely to be server writable such as a cache or CMS writable image repository.